# Email validation and not letting the visitor to pass if the email is invalid

Tags: javascript, html, forms, shopify

We have a Shopify store and i have a script which validates the email adress and writes out if the email address is not good, another script is checking if the form is filled out and if it's not - it's not letting the customer to pass the next stage based on ID selector.

I only need this email validator to do the same thing as the other script, write out an alert when the email address is not correct and don't let them pass to the next step.

Can someone help with this? How to do that?

**Script which validates the email address:**

```
const validateEmail = (email) => {
return email.match(
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
);
};

const validate = () => {
const $result = $('#result');
const email = $('#email').val();
$result.text('');

if (validateEmail(email)) {
$result.text(email + ' e-mail address is valid!');
$result.css('color', 'green');
} else {
$result.text(email + ' Lūdzu, ievadiet derīgu e-pastu lai pabeigt pirkumu');
$result.css('color', 'red');
}
return false;
}

$('#email').on('input', validate);
```

**Script which checks wheter the form was filled out or not:**

```
 document.getElementById("cart__checkout").onclick = function() {
  let allAreFilled = true;
  document.getElementById("myForm").querySelectorAll("[required]").forEach(function(i) {
    if (!allAreFilled) return;
    if (i.type === "radio") {
      let radioValueCheck = false;
document.getElementById("myForm").querySelectorAll(`[name=${i.name}]`).forEach(function(r) {
        if (r.checked) radioValueCheck = true;
      })
      allAreFilled = radioValueCheck;
      return;
    }
    if (!i.value) { allAreFilled = false;  return; }
  })
  if (!allAreFilled) {
    alert('Lūdzu, ievadiet Jūsu e-pastu lai pabeigt pirkumu!');
  }

};
```

Appreciate the help, what i'm missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the email validation inside on onClick event like this and set the var `allAreFilled` `false` is email validation failed

```
document.getElementById("cart__checkout").onclick = function() {
  let allAreFilled = true;
  document.getElementById("myForm").querySelectorAll("[required]").forEach(function(i) {
    if (!allAreFilled) return;
    if (i.type === "radio") {
      let radioValueCheck = false;
document.getElementById("myForm").querySelectorAll(`[name=${i.name}]`).forEach(function(r) {
        if (r.checked) radioValueCheck = true;
      })
      allAreFilled = radioValueCheck;
      return;
    }
    if (!i.value) { allAreFilled = false;  return; }
  });

  /* Here email valdation */

  const email = $('#email').val();
  if( !email.match(
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
)){
   allAreFilled = false;
  }
  /* terms and condtions check */
  if( !$('#CartTermsDrawer').is(':checked') ){
   allAreFilled = false;
  }

  if (!allAreFilled) {
    alert('Lūdzu, ievadiet Jūsu e-pastu lai pabeigt pirkumu!');
    return;
  }

};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the script is working - i have the alert however after clicking the "OK" button - it redirects to the next step. Not preventing the user to procceed. Why is that?

Comment: after alert code you need simple `return;` to prevent it from next page.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i forgot to mention we also have a terms and condition box and probably that's why it's letting me to pass through after clicking OK. Do you know by any chance how to also include that in the code?

Comment: {% if settings.cart_terms_conditions_enable %}
            <div class="cart__item-row cart__terms">
              <input type="checkbox" id="CartTermsDrawer" class="cart__terms-checkbox">
              <label for="CartTermsDrawer">
                {% if settings.cart_terms_conditions_link != blank %}
                  {{ 'cart.general.terms_html' | t: url: settings.cart_terms_conditions_link }}
                {% else %}
                  {{ 'cart.general.terms' | t }}
                {% endif %}
              </label>
            </div>
          {% endif %}

Comment: update the code and add code to check the checkbox also

Comment: Thank you for your help,  i had to add return false in the end. But i got it, everything is working perfectly. Much appreciate!